# Delete a saved Image in Python on Raspberry Pi with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm programming a Lego sorter machine. I using the following hardware: Raspberry Pi and a Piface I/O module. On the Raspberry runs OpenCV 2.4.1 and the script is written in Python.

The following problem appears:
I'm making every 5 second a picture of a Lego block. After 30 seconds it will be slower and slower and after approx. 40 seconds the RPI kills the application.

With the command top in LX terminal you can see that the memory of the python shell is growing and growing. After every picture the memory use increase with 5%. Is there a command that to delete the memory or even better to delete the saved image?

Kind regards,
Richard

Comment: Did you forget cvReleaseImage for IplImages? You can't delete a file with OpenCV, but you can save on top of one a tiny other.

Comment: are you using `cv2.imwrite('imageName',image)` to save the images? perhaps you could post some of your code snippet so that your question is more clear.